# How do I get hardware ID of input source device in java?

Tags: java, hardware-id

I'm working on a java project, in which I need to decide, from which keyboard the input comes from (both atteched to the computer via USB). Is there any way to get the ID of the device in java?

Comment: How do you process input? java.awt? GLFW? Something else?

Comment: Well yes, awt. It is a swing application, but in the background I want it to process input coming from a different source, but that I did not yet figure out how to.

Comment: Well, you can't with AWT/Swing.